# Currency used in Switzerland and France

Tags: france, money, switzerland

I will be travelling to Métabief, France in the coming weekends.

Currently I am in a dilemma. As I will be landing in Geneva Airport in Switzerland, I need to take public transport in Switzerland so that I can reach Metabief, France.

I am not sure whether Euro is applicable to both France and Switzerland. I know that Euro is accepted in France but Switzerland has its own currency, that is Swiss Franc.

Comment: How exactly are you planning to travel to Metabief. It looks complicated enough to get there by public transport without even considering the means of payment.

Comment: I have booked an SBB train ticket online from airport to Vallorbe. As I am attending a conference at Metabief, either the organizer arranges a transport to pick me up at Vallorbe or I take public transport.

Comment: Then to ask once again and more precise: How exactly are you planning to get from Vallorbe to Métabief? We do not have crystal balls and how to pay will depend on which trasnport company you are intending to use. The only bus I can find from Vallorbe to Métabief leaves 5:51am Mo-Fr (except school holidays) and is probably not a good choice unless you plan to stay overnight in Vallorbe.

Comment: And since you were told in several answers to your previous question that there is no reasonable options for public transport from Vallorbe to Métabief, but to take a taxi, I will vote to close this question as unclear.  If you really wanted to go to Métabief by public transport, you should have taken the train to Frasne (not Vallorbe) and a bus from there.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The question here is just about currencies required, nothing unclear about that. As the OP already has a SBB train ticket booked, there is a high chance that they don't even need any Swiss Francs at all.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: The OP has already asked several questions here about how to reach Métabief. There's no need to rehash them all once again.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I understood the question as if OP intends to buy tickets for public transport from Geneva Airport to Métabief and wants to know which currency is required. If public transport from Switzerland to France can be paid with Euros, or if Swis francs are required, depends entirely on which transport company OP is going to travel with. That is why I am asking. If the question is not related to payment of public transport, but merely if Euros are accepted in Switzerland (for arbitrary purchases), the question should anyway be redacted to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

Different countries, different currencies.

Since your starting point will in in Switzerland, you will have to pay in Swiss Franc.

Maybe your transport company accepts Euros, but don't plan on it.

You could pay with Credit Card which removes the burden of having to have Swiss currencies.

Comment: Actually, *some* Geneva public transports do accept euro coins in vending machines (http://www.tpg.ch/fr/web/guest/moyens-de-paiement). It might be worth checking with the company involved with the OP transportation.

Comment: It is not uncommon at all that Euros are accepted in Swiss border areas, although usually at a poor exchange rate. Just for paying small amounts, it may however be more convenient to accept the poor exchange rate than to bother with getting Swiss cash.

Comment: @audionuma But a foreign traveller is likely to have only notes, at least at first.

Comment: SBB ticket vending machines (for the ticket to Vallorbe) accept Euro notes. But better use your credit card.

Answer (score 3):

The Geneva airport is on the border and has a Swiss sector and a French sector. To go to France you simply walk through the doorway to the French part of the airport.

There is a good chance you will not need a Swiss franc in your journey.

Comment: Well, try to get from GVA to Metabief. From the Swiss side, complicated. From the french side, probably borders on the impossible.